# Using MATLAB to create a latin square matrix

Tags: matlab, latin-square

I'm pretty rusty at MATLAB and I'm trying to brush up by automating some Latin square problems. The code I'm working on is as follows:

```
counter=1;
for i=1:10
    for j=1:10
        if A(i,j)=0
            A(i,j)=[This is where I'm stuck];
        end
        counter=counter+1;
    end
end
```

I would like this code to check the values in `A(i,j)` to determine whether or not a value from `[1,...,n]` is already present in the ith row, and then pick random value from

```
[1,...,n] excluding [values already present].
```

Basically I'm just trying to brute force the completion of partial latin squares.

Edit:

I'm not trying to generate random latin squares, but rather ones with certain properties in place.  For example, suppose we have the following setup:

```
A=[X,0,0,0,Y,0,0,0,Z]
```

Where 0,X,Y,Z are all 3x3 submatrices and X,Y,Z have values from 1,...,9 in them.  I'm trying to devise an automated approach to completing a partial latin squares which have some values in place.

Comment: You likely want `if A(i,j) == 0` (comparison) instead of `if A(i,j) = 0` (assignment)

Comment: Why brute force? [`toeplitz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) is your friend: `latin = toeplitz(1:10, [1 10:-1:2]); newLatin = latin(randperm(10), randperm(10));`

Comment: ...or [`hankel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html): `latin = hankel(1:10, [10 1:9]); newLatin = latin(randperm(10), randperm(10));`

Comment: I've expanded on @gnovice's comment in an answer because it was spot on and worth some context :) as an aside, if you're looking at brushing up on mathematical coding skills, I recommend [https://projecteuler.net/](https://projecteuler.net/) for short algorithmic challenges, since the likes of `toeplitz` might not be broadly applicable in your future Matlab career!

Answer (score 0):

The method you describe isn't robust enough to generate a Latin square every time. For instance, imagine we are calculating the 2nd row of a 5x5 square

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 1 3 ?
```

The first 4 columns obeyed the rules, choosing random values in each column which don't result in a row/column clash. Then the last value must be a 5 which isn't allowed. You could add another stage which would cycle through clashes and make swaps, but this could be endless if not carefully constructed!

A much easier method would be to construct a "simple" Latin square of size `n` with the following form:

```
A = [1    2    3    ...    n-1  n
     n    1    2    ...    n-2  n-1
     n-1  n    1    ...    n-3  n-2
     ...  ...  ...  ...    ...  ...
     3    4    5    ...    1    2  
     2    3    4    ...    n    1   ]
```

Each row is the vector `1:n` permuted by one element each row. This can be generated easily in Matlab using [`toeplitz`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html):

```
A = toeplitz([1,n:-1:2],1:n);
```

Now we have a Latin square! You could randomise this process by making the row permutations random, not ordered. We can do this afterwards, and permute the columns too, using random indices from [`randperm`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html)

```
A = A(randperm(n), randperm(n));
```

---

Note, this won't yield all of the possible Latin squares, since:

"*Two squares are in the same isotopy class if one can be obtained from the other by permuting rows, columns and symbols*" [Brendan McKay](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/latin.html)

Looking at hopping between classes would be another level. There are over 1 million classes for n=8, and the number of classes explodes rapidly for higher values! [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Equivalence_classes_of_Latin_squares)

---

Since **there are 9,982,437,658,213,039,871,725,064,756,920,320,000 Latin squares for n=10** (as in your attempt) I think it's safe to say neither your brute force method nor this permutation method will exhaust them quickly anyway!

---

Disclosure: this answer was based on gnovice's comment, which was worth expanding on for context and links.

Comment: Haha thanks.  I do appreciate the method you provided.  I forgot to add this detail.  The reason why I have this a(i,j)=0 is because there are values in the latin square which I don't want changed.  The non-zero values are placed there with a purpose.

Comment: Basically, I do not want just any latin square.  But I want a completed latin square based on certain values which are already present.  I then want MATLAB to flip the 0's to the appropriate value and leave the rest alone.

Comment: Like solving a sudoku? Please edit your question to give an example input.

Comment: Not necessarily a sudoku.  But let's say we have a 9x9 partial latin square with 3 3x3 blocks already completed.  I want to figure out a way to brute force complete it.